# HTMLAgilityPach - How to get a child div ignoring subgroups

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I have these two following `HTML`:

```
-- first HTML
<div id="FIRST">
  <span>foo</span>
  <div id="SECOND">
      <span>bar</span>
  </div>
</div>

-- second HTML
<div id="FIRST">
  <div id="SECOND">
      <span>bar</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like to get the `span` inside the FIRST `div` on the first `HTML`, but there are situations when this span inside the FIRST `div` doesn't exists as you can see on the second `HTML`.

Now I am using the following code, but the code is getting the span inside the SECOND `div`.

```
SelectSingleNode(".//span")
```

Obs: Remember that in my example I have only two levels of `divs` but in my real `HTML` I have a loooooooot of levels.

**I need to get the `span` considering only tags in the first div**

Comment: `//div[id="FIRST"]/span`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get only `<span>`s that is direct child of the `<div id="FIRST">`, you can either use `./span` or `span`, assuming that the context where you want to call `SelectSingleNode()` is the aforementioned `<div id="FIRST">` :

```
SelectSingleNode("./span")
SelectSingleNode("span")
```

Comment: Oh god, so easy and a spent a lot of time searching. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative:

```
SelectSingleNode("span[1]");
```

This selects the first span element in the HtmlDocument